# Keeping JavaScript state in an ePub's spine

Tags: epub, ibooks

Is it possible to keep code state across pages in an ePub? More specifically do readers like iBooks allow this type of state?

```
              spine.js
        +---------+----------+        
        |         |          | 
+--------+   +--------+  +--------+
| Page 1 |   | Page 2 |  | Page   |
| Quiz1  |   |  Quiz2 |  | (n)    |
|        |   |        |  | Result |
|        |   |        |  |        |
+--------+   +--------+  +--------+
```

In this example, the last page could contain a score but state is required.  WebSQL is out of the question since it's not supported by webkit ereaders and websockets demand a connection. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

No. Each HTML file is independent. To share information, you'll need to use some kind of local storage such as window.localStorage, but it's very hard to find out what device supports what level of HTML5.

UPDATE: [This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3686472?start=0&tstart=0) says localStorage is in fact supported.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately localStorage is broken.  I decided to use cookies instead.